# Find overlapping dates ranges and delete duplicates from Fact tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below table with overlapping dates and need to identify and get rid of it from the same table and other fact tables which have these records.

Current Output is:

```
select pcode,pkey, RowEffectiveDate ,rowenddate from dimP
where pcode='KO18'

Pcode   Pkey      RowEffectiveDate        rowenddate
KO18    3023    1900-01-01 00:00:00.000  2017-12-06 23:59:59.997
KO18    6328    2017-12-07 00:00:00.000  2018-01-29 23:59:59.997
KO18    8550    2018-01-30 00:00:00.000  2018-02-09 23:59:59.997
KO18    8847    2018-02-10 00:00:00.000  2018-04-24 23:59:59.997
KO18    8848    2018-02-10 00:00:00.000  2018-04-25 23:59:59.997
KO18    8896    2018-02-10 00:00:00.000  2018-04-26 23:59:59.997
KO18    8897    2018-02-10 00:00:00.000  2018-04-29 23:59:59.997
KO18    11506   2018-04-25 00:00:00.000  2018-04-25 23:59:59.997
KO18    11817   2018-04-26 00:00:00.000  2018-04-26 23:59:59.997
KO18    11825   2018-04-27 00:00:00.000  2018-04-29 23:59:59.997
KO18    11849   2018-04-30 00:00:00.000  9999-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

expected output1: Identify the overlapping Pkey

```
Pcode Pkeytobeaffected  PkeytobeRetained      RowEffectiveDate        rowenddate
KO18    3023                3023            1900-01-01 00:00:00.000  2017-12-06 23:59:59.997
KO18    6328                6328            2017-12-07 00:00:00.000  2018-01-29 23:59:59.997
KO18    8550                8550            2018-01-30 00:00:00.000  2018-02-09 23:59:59.997
KO18    8847                8847            2018-02-10 00:00:00.000  2018-04-24 23:59:59.997
KO18    8848                8847            2018-02-10 00:00:00.000  2018-04-25 23:59:59.997
KO18    8896                8847            2018-02-10 00:00:00.000  2018-04-26 23:59:59.997
KO18    8897                8847            2018-02-10 00:00:00.000  2018-04-29 23:59:59.997
KO18    11506               11506           2018-04-25 00:00:00.000  2018-04-25 23:59:59.997
KO18    11817               11817           2018-04-26 00:00:00.000  2018-04-26 23:59:59.997
KO18    11825               11825           2018-04-27 00:00:00.000  2018-04-29 23:59:59.997
KO18    11849               11849           2018-04-30 00:00:00.000  9999-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

expected output 2: Delete the Overlapping Pkey(I am not able to display Pkey with this query, this is just a try to display what i need with sql)

```
select pcode, Min(RowEffectiveDate) RowEffectiveDate, Min(RowEndDate) RowEndDate
from
(
    select *,
        NewStartDate = t.RowEffectiveDate+v.number,
        NewStartDateGroup =
            dateadd(d,
                    1- DENSE_RANK() over (partition by RowEffectiveDate order by t.RowEffectiveDate+v.number),
                    t.RowEffectiveDate+v.number)
    from dimP t
    inner join master..spt_values v
      on v.type='P' and v.number <= DATEDIFF(d, RowEffectiveDate, RowEndDate)
      where PCode='KO18'
) X
group by PCode,RowEffectiveDate, NewStartDateGroup
order by PCode, RowEffectiveDate

Pcode           Pkey                RowEffectiveDate          RowEndDate
KO18            3023            1900-01-01 00:00:00.000     2017-12-06 23:59:59.997
KO18            6328            2017-12-07 00:00:00.000     2018-01-29 23:59:59.997
KO18            8550            2018-01-30 00:00:00.000     2018-02-09 23:59:59.997
KO18            8847            2018-02-10 00:00:00.000     2018-04-24 23:59:59.997
KO18            11506           2018-04-25 00:00:00.000     2018-04-25 23:59:59.997
KO18            11817           2018-04-26 00:00:00.000     2018-04-26 23:59:59.997
KO18            11825           2018-04-27 00:00:00.000     2018-04-29 23:59:59.997
KO18            11849           2018-04-30 00:00:00.000     9999-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

Expected output 3: Also, find and delete this Pkey from other fact tables.

P.S: RowEffectiveDate should be the next day of RowEndDate

Answer (score 1):

Use `first_value()` function :

```
select *, first_value(Pkey) over (Partition by Pcode, RowEffectiveDate order by RowEndDate) as PkeytobeRetained
from dimP t;
```

Comment: Thanks @YogeshSharma But can you show me this solution in my query. Also,I think this provide me with just 1 output, can you also help me with the other output as well.

Comment: I got the first output with your query. But how do i get the second output?

Comment: @Sanky. . . This is a bad habit to ask one question with three different requirements.

Comment: Sorry @Yogeshsharma . I am still a learner, but i understand your point. When i tried asking for another question related to this one, it was marked negative. How should i proceed?